# How to mount a volume and copy a file into docker container in gitlab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci

I have the following gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages: 
  - test_dev
  
Postman_Tests_Dev: 
  stage: test_dev
  image:
    name: postman/newman
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  script:
    - newman --version
  tags:
    - docker-azure
```

It seems to be working fine in that I can see the newman version number being printed.  now I need to run a test by doing something like "newman run ".

Before I do that I, I need to copy my json file from the gitlab repository into the container.
The file lives in ./postmantests - relative to the gitlab-ci.yml file. I'm presently googling but I think my keywords are wrong.

what I'd like to see is if there's something like this:

```
stages: 
  - test_dev

Postman_Tests_Dev: 
  stage: test_dev
  image:
    name: postman/newman
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    volume: postmantests:/etc/newman
  script:
    - newman --version
    - newman run /etc/newman/myjsontest.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You probably need to build you own image based on `postman/newman` and add the volume there.

Afterwards you can use this image in `image`.